# Can I use Delphi 10.3 or 10.4 Professional to connect to a remote Firebird database using FireDAC?

Tags: delphi

I would like to upgrade my XE5 Professional to 10.3 or 10.4 Professional, but I've a doubt. Using a Professional edition and FireDAC components, can I connect to Firebird 2.5 on a server in my intranet? The feature-matrix document says "Connect to **local** databases...".

See https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/product-editions

With my XE5 Professional, I can connect, and a few months ago I tried the Community edition of 10.3 and even with that edition I had the opportunity to connect.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not what you are *able* to do, but rather what you are *allowed* to do. The relevant part of the license says (emphasize by me):

> Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement, Licensor grants
>   to Licensee as the licensed user of the Product the limited right to
>   use those portions of the Product identified as "dbExpress" and
>   “FireDAC”, in executable form only, **to access a local database
>   installed on the same machine as the Work**. Licensee **may not use** that
>   portion of the Product identified as "dbExpress" or “FireDAC” in
>   association with **a database located on a different machine other than
>   the machine on which the Works are installed**.

In your case this limits the connections to Firebird servers running on the same machine your program is running on. Simply the Firebird server being in the local intranet is not sufficient.

[Software License and Support Agreement](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/rad-studio-eula)

Comment: Yeah, I never understood that.  We've always used the Professional SKU and use FireDAC (as a client) for all kinds of things across many applications, all of them connecting to a separate MySQL server over a LAN.  We don't produce any commercial software, of course, so maybe it is just a licencing thing?  Definitely FireDAC exists in the Pro SKU and it works.

Comment: It's exactly our situation, client application connected at our server over our lan, none  commercial application.

Comment: The mentioned paragraph from the license terms targets the Community Edition as well. So to use Delphi in the way you describe you need an Enterprise or higher SKU to adhere to the license. At least that is my understanding, but IANAL.

Comment: Great way to promote using FireDac though, in particular in connection with the (in my opinion totally overpriced) licenses for Interbase. But hey, there is always ADO.

Comment: @UweRaabe:  I used to be in the Intellectual Property business and I'm pretty sure your interpretation, that it's a question of what the livence permits, rather than what is technicaly possible, which is the decider.

Comment: Embarcadero used to offer `FireDAC Client/Server Add-On Pack` for professional edition which would then allow you to connect to remote servers using FireDac. Similar they offered `Mobile ad-on pack` for professional edition of Delphi. But I can't find any up-to date information on `FireDAC Client/Server Add-On Pack`. So I'm guessing Embarcadero might have removed it since because `Mobile add-on pack` are already included in Professional edition of Delphi the only difference between Professional and Enterprise edition are features of `FireDAC Client/Server Add-On Pack`.

Comment: Correct, FireDAC C/S Add-On Pack is no longer available.